# How to keep main text centered while moving first two words to the left

Tags: css, html-table, responsive-design, flexbox, overlay

I have a two line bullet. We want to keep the text centered on the entire width but move "Our Vision" to the left. While keeping the two words (Our Vision) on the same line we want to vertically align it to the middle of the green bar.  This is for a responsive design.  Here's a picture:

[image]

```css
#vision-table{
  display:table;
  margin:1.3509375vw 0;
  border:solid .5px black; 
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
#vision{
  background-color:#538231c7;
  color:white;
  height:3.71385vw;
  padding:1.00215vw 2.01vw;
  line-height:1.5;
  font-size:1.35vw;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="vision-table">
   <div id="vision">Our Vision: A sustainable and healthy town of                         Weston, with engaged citizens committed<br>
                    to a thriving community, today and in the future.    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean move "Our Vision" to the left? You mean have it float all the way over by itself to the left? The way you have it, it is centered both vertically and horizontally

Comment: @keith, yes we want to float Our Vision to the left, and then vertically center it, as it is now it's on the top line.

Comment: OK, so if you want it vertically centered in the green bar, then it can't stay on the same line as the first line. Did you just mean you want to keep it in the same div as the other text but vertically aligned to the container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using absolute position ?

```css
#vision-table{
  display:table;
  margin:1.3509375vw 0;
  border:solid .5px black; 
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
#vision{
  background-color:#538231c7;
  color:white;
  height:3.71385vw;
  padding:1.00215vw 2.01vw;
  line-height:1.5;
  font-size:1.35vw;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  position: relative;
}
.vision-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10vw;
   top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.26vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="vision-table">
<div id="vision"><span class="vision-left">Our Vision:</span> A sustainable and healthy town of                         Weston, with engaged citizens committed<br>
                    to a thriving community, today and in the future.    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's close, but it isn't centering Our Vision vertically in a responsive design

Answer (score 3):

Use display:flex. There is a lot of good examples out there. Its really worth learning if you want to create responsive and modern design

css

```css
#statement{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: #538231c7;
      color:white;
      padding:1em;
      font-size:1.35em;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
#statement div:first-child{
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-grow: 0.4;
}
#statement div:last-child{
  padding-left: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #statement{
    display: block;
  }
  #statement div:first-child{
    padding-bottom:1em;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  #statement {
    font-size: 1.35vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="statement">
        <div>Our Vision</div>
        <div>Our Vision: A sustainable and healthy town of Weston, with engaged citizens committed<br>
          to a thriving community, today and in the future.
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to respond.  Your example however doesn't come close to solving the problem.  You'll notice the flexbot tag as I think you might be in the right direction.  Although, I think using an overlay might be easier but I'm not sure how to do those.

Comment: Could you try to describe little more how you would like it to look like? My html now looks like yours apart from mine that has Our vision to the left and is vertical aligned with less css. If you could maybe show with a paint program I’m sure I can reproduce it

Comment: I made yours a snippet and added a font-size:1.5vw.  So, with the  responsive font this is a lot closer.  But the text is not being centered across the entire green bar, and then have OUR VISION somewhat to the left. Need this to work when browser is resized

Comment: Just added a picture

Comment: Added first and last child selectors so that you can add any font and padding to the two inner elements. Also added text-align:center to the last child. If there's any regarding responsive we can add media queries. Regarding the left position you can lower the padding-left on the outer box. You can also use the flex-grow on any child element to give it more percentage of the 'row'

Comment: thanks but run the accepted answer to see a different approach that works

Comment: I have updated the answer. I think this is better in smallest size, you can still read the text. Need to run sniplet in fullpage.